# Oracle 11g stored procs: SELECT ALL_ARGUMENTS not returning certain values in certain cases

Tags: stored-procedures, oracle11g

I'm doing a select on the ALL_ARGUMENTS like:

```
SELECT
    count(*) FROM all_arguments
WHERE owner LIKE 'MYSCHEMA' ESCAPE '/'
    AND object_name LIKE 'MYSTOREDPROC' ESCAPE '/'
    AND package_name LIKE 'MYPACKAGE' ESCAPE '/';
```

Sometimes, after connecting to the DB after a certain period of time, I get a result = 0, althought the Stored Procedure is there. Immediatelly after that I retry, and I get result = 2.

Why is that? Does the SELECT recompile the stored proc?

EDIT: The query is weird, I know, but it's just because it was assembled by the ojdbc driver.

Comment: Why are you using `LIKE` if you are not using any wildcards? Also: are you aware that the names are usually all uppercase in Oracle? At least if you created the package without quoting the names.

Comment: I changed the uppercase/lowercase. Anyway, the query is weird because I got it from the ojdbc driver. So I don't really see how your comment relates to the answer.

Comment: If the query comes from the JDBC driver then it explains the presence of the `LIKE`. The JDBC API defines the arguments to various metadata methods to be wildcard expressions. The driver simply uses a `LIKE` all the time rather than parsing the values and changing the SQL accordingly. Did changing the name to uppercase yield better results?

Comment: No. Neither the 'like' or 'character case' are in question. The desctiption of the issue reads: Sometimes, after connecting to the DB after a certain period of time, I get a result = 0, althought the Stored Procedure is there. Immediatelly after that I retry, and I get result = 2.